# SVG to Font (IcoMoon) Create Multiple Path

Tags: css, svg, fonts, type-conversion

I'm using [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io) to convert my svg file into font but what i got is something like this
[image]

I want to use my font such like this

```
<span class="icon-Electronic"></span>
```

instead of this

```
<span class="icon-Electronic"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span><span class="path3"></span><span class="path4"></span><span class="path5"></span><span class="path6"></span><span class="path7"></span><span class="path8"></span><span class="path9"></span><span class="path10"></span><span class="path11"></span><span class="path12"></span></span>
```

what's wrong with my step? i need help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have multiple paths in your svg file,
You will need to merge them together externally and import it again

If you have access to Adobe Illustrator,

1. Open file in Illustrator
2. Select all
3. Go to Object > Path >Outline stroke
4. Then select all
5. Go to Windows > Pathfinder > Merge
6. Then save it and import again

*You can record this as an action in Illustrator for future use*

The above methods can be replicated in any other vector editing software like Inkscape(free). The steps will be almost same, 
But **merging** is very important.